# How can I listen for signals from Docker in .Net Core Executable?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a console application written in .Net Core. I will be running this in a Docker container.  I would like to gracefully stop the process when a docker stop command is given, rather than just letting the process get killed in the middle of doing something.  Is there a way that I can listen for this signal from within the console application?  Before containers, I would just have the console app listen for something to be typed in the console window.  If there is a way to have docker send a message through standard input, I could work with that, I just do not know enough about Docker, yet, to know what is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is going to end up being to not use a console application, after all.  I learned that if I create a web project, I can tell when the container has requested a shutdown with the ApplicationStopping CancellationToken in the website's Startup.  So, rather than having the container start up a long running console application, it will just host a website that has no web content.  The website will just start up my long running process, and when the container sends a signal to the website that it is shutting down, my process can gracefully stop.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app
                , IHostingEnvironment env
                , IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(ApplicationStarted);
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(ApplicationStopping);
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(ApplicationStopped);
}
```

Comment: I have the same code, but when executing the below command. Nothing is triggered in the .net code
docker kill --signal=SIGTERM containerID

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a command to a running process in a Docker container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: this document shows how to send a signal through Docker, but how can I read the signal in the .Net Core code?